# change and show background image in ios

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I am writing an app, where I programmatically display a background image and then update some text over the top.

On some event (e.g. a tap), I want to change the text and background image.

I am able to change the text successfully, but the image, is not changing.

I setup the image with the following code, where `view`, `images1` and `images2` are:

```
UIImageView* view;
UIImage* images1;
UIImage* images2;

view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image1];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
[view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:view];
[self.view setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:view];
```

and then I try to change the background with:

```
view.image = image2;
```

but the image does not change, any ideas?

Comment: Use multiple views...

Comment: what are image1 and image2?where do you have the image?

Comment: images1 and images2 are setup with uiImages1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/1.jpg"];
    uiImages2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images/2.jpg"]; and both work and are loaded ok

Comment: you need initialize `images2` alloc init

Comment: @Rafouille I hadn't thought of that, will research that idea and try thanks.  I thought from the documentation it would be a simple reassign

Comment: @jose920405 do you mean the UIImage variables must alloc init? Does the first only work because I alloc init the UIImageView?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to change the image on tap gesture

First you have to define UIImageView in header file like this.

```
@interface ChangeImageViewController ()
UIImageView *Imgview;
@end
@implementation ChangeImageViewController


Imgview=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
Imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImageName.png"];
[Imgview setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:Imgview];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:Imgview];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(TaponImgview:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired=1;
[Imgview addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

And In Tap Gesture Recognizer Method.

```
-(void)TaponImgview:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
   Imgview.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImage.png"]; // Your second image that you want to change it

}
```

And So finally your image will change on tap on UIImageview..Thanks